# How to do the sum in individual line one by one in linux?

Tags: awk

How to do the sum in individual line in Linux?

I have one file :

```
Course Name: Math
Credit: 4
12345 1 4 5 1 1 1 1 1 5 10 1 2 2 20
34567 2 3 4 1 10 5 3 2 5 5 10 20 5
Course Name: English
Credit: 4
12345 1 4 5 1 1 1 1 1 5 10 1 20
34567 4 1 10 5 3 2 5 5 10 20 5
```

Its output will be come:

```
Course Name: Math
Credit: 4
12345     55
34567     75
Course Name: English
Credit: 4
12345     51
34567     70
```

I tried this code:

```
awk '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {tot += $1}; print $1 "\t" tot; tot =0}' file > file2
```

The output is like this:

```
Course Name: 0
Credit: 4
12345     55
34567     75
Course Name: 0
Credit: 4
12345     51
34567     70
```

Actually I need to display a Course name too (Math and English). I am trying to fix it but I couldn't. Can you please help?

Comment: You're in the same class as [this chap](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1050667/user1050667) I suppose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
awk '/^[0-9]/{for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {tot += $i}; print $1 "\t" tot; tot =0} !/^[0-9]/'
```

This will only sum lines that start with a digit, and simply print those that don't.

Comment: @Shawn  Thanks, fixed.  One should never blindly copy the code given in the question!

Answer (score 0):

Just with the shell

```
while read line; do
  case $line in   
    Course*|Credit*) echo "$line" ;;
    *) set -- $line
       id=$1
       shift 1
       sum=$(IFS=+; echo "$*" | bc)
       printf "%s\t%d\n" $id $sum
       ;;
  esac
done  < filename
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you too!

```
sed '/:/{s/.*/echo "&"/;b};s/ /+/2g;s/\(\S*\) \(.*\)/echo "\1\t\$((\2))"/' file | sh
```